# Apache Ant: Could not find or load main class set on Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: java, windows, ant

I am getting this error after installing Ant on Windows 7.

[command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWqAL.jpg)
[image]

I have set the `PATH`, `ANT_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` variables correctly.

```
ANT_HOME = C:\Ant\1.10.1

PATH = %ANT_HOME%\bin
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as it worked sometime ago when I tested it but has stopped working after a restart. I checked the other posts as well and tried specifying the full path under `PATH` variable but it didn't help.

Any other ideas would be helpful.

Comment: May be your ant is missing some things? Let's try to download a new one

Comment: Can you type the command `java` and see what happens? If that works, type command `jar` and update the question.

Comment: i faced same issue, but re-download and re-install solved the issue.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen, tried that but it didn't help. Still have the same issue

Comment: @Rao, I can see the java usage options and jar options doing that.

Comment: @ThiruShetty, tried it but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by removing the ANT_OPTS variable. That was causing the issue. Thanks everyone!